# VHDL process assignment does not work

Tags: process, vhdl, variable-assignment

I do have following VHDL code snipped:

```
signal state_last_pushbutton                    : std_logic;    

process (clk_clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_clk) then
        userleds_external_connection_export(0) <= '0';
    else
        userleds_external_connection_export(0) <= '1';
    end if;

    state_last_pushbutton <= pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0); 

end process;
```

Question:

Why the signal **state_last_pushbutton** never gets the value of **pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0)**? In the simulation its value remains always 'U'.

Thanks

Comment: What else is driving that signal?

Comment: Your code works for me in ModelSim DE 10.4c. You're not saying anything about the value of pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0) though, any chance that signal is also set to 'U'?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to write a clocked process, in which case you should probably write something like this:

```
signal state_last_pushbutton : std_logic;    

process (clk_clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_clk) then
      state_last_pushbutton <= pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0); 
    end if;
end process;
```

This will update `state_last_pushbutton` to the value stored in the register or signal `pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0)` on each rising edge of the clock.

Have you checked that `pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0)` is actually set to some known value, and that your clock is running properly?

Comment: Ok but **pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0)** needs to be set depending on the clk-edge (see my example code)

Comment: Please try to explain what it is that you are trying to do. Do you need to set it low on rising edge and high on falling edge? It's hard to understand your code as it is obviously bugged.

Comment: that **state_last_pushbutton** gets the value from **pushbuttons_external_connection_export(0); ** depending on the clock edge (0 or 1)

Comment: Seems like you a looking a a signal called `userleds_external_connection_export` in the if statement. Plus the else should probably be `elsif falling_edge(clk_clk)`